# How can I make a program executable from everywhere in a MACOS Monterey 12.01

Tags: macos, command-line

I want to make nextflow https://www.nextflow.io/ or any other program executable from every directory in my MAC termninal.

I have done my research which says find the ~/.bashrc file and write in there

```
export PATH=$PATH:</path/to/file/>
```

In my MACOS Monterey 12.01 there is no ~/.bashrc file but a ~/.zshrc file. Shall I add the command on the ~/.zshrc or I have to create a ~/.bashrc. If I have to create a ~/.bashrc how do I do this?

Sorry for the basic question

Comment: You need to add the path to the directory the program is in, not the path to the program itself (and don't use a trailing slash). Also, at least for bash the previous `$PATH` should be double-quoted (the added directory may also be inside the double-quotes, unless it starts with `~` in which case it needs to be unquoted): `export PATH="$PATH":</path/to/directory>`

Answer (score 3):

In the past, you had to decide, which of the terminal types you want to choose. Your tutorial is maybe already deprecated, because the change of the terminal system already appeared. Now it should be the `~/.zshrc` or maybe the `~/.zshenv` file, that does what you want.

On my MacOS Monterey 12.1 Beta the `zshenv` file is used to setup global things

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you add it to the ~/.zshrc and see if it works? My guess is that it does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Do as Gordon suggested. Add your program into your PATH export PATH="$PATH":</path/to/directory>. Restart terminal, and then you ll be able to execute command from anywhere